# How to delete the tokens of my text if it is not in vocabulary?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I define vocabulary and texte and I wand delete the tokens of my text if it is not in vocabulary.

```
vocbulary=['Get','owns', 'about', 'for', 'to', 'by', 'person', 'movie', 'school', 'Movie', 'Person']
    texte=["good morning i oll know most terrible things you've done in your life up to this point but clearly a commons ot of balance to get a sign to my class i professor annile's keeting and this is criminal law one hundred or as i prefered to college ow to get away with murder\nunlike many of my colleagues i will not be teaching you how to study the law a theorize about it but rather how to practise what was the men"]
    
    for word in nltk.word_tokenize(texte):
      if word not in vocabulary:
         x = re.sub(word," ", texte)
```

this is x return:

```
x 
    'good morning i oll know most terrible things you've done in your life up to this point but clearly a commons ot of balance to get a sign to my class i professor annile's keeting and this is criminal law one hundred or as i prefered to college ow to get away with murder\nunlike many of my colleagues i will not be teaching you how to study the law a theorize about it but rather how to practise what was the men'
```

Comment: `nltk.word_tokenize(texte)` is wrong, it is a list of strings, but `nltk.word_tokenize()` accepts a string. So, use something like `x = [w for sent in texte for w in nltk.word_tokenize(sent) if w in vocbulary]`. BTW, is it really what you want to get? `['to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'to', 'about', 'to']`?

Comment: Thanks for your proposition . I try that but i want to take the sentence array and check one by one in vocabulary. If one element is not in vocabulary i delete. This allow me to keep my shape sentence in x variable. Sorry if I'm not making myself understood or if you have any other indication for me. Thank you.

Comment: Theoretically you could join all the words using an alternation, then just use a single `sub(r"\b(?:to|school|person|owns|movie|for|by|about|Person|Movie|Get)\b", "", texte)`

Comment: Ok thank Sir. I 'm trying